# Dual booting Ubuntu 13.10 x64 and Windows 7 Ultimate N x64?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 13.10, windows-7, uefi

I'm having trouble installing alongside my Win 7 Ubuntu 13.10. It's not the first time I dual boot Ubuntu and Windows but this time, during the installation, when I get to where you'r supposed to pick the disk and partition where to install Ubuntu it doesn't show me the option for installing it alongside my Windows 7 Ultimate N x64 (the N version is the stripped down version of windows) and when I tried creating the partition myself and fix GRUB using boot-repair it just did not start anymore in any of the OSs. Can someone help me? Thanks!!!

**EDIT:** I think the problem might be that the "new" (it's acctually 1 year old, only that I didn't do dual boot on this one yet) motherboard I installed uses UEFI for booting windows. I'll give a try with the guides regarding that.

Comment: I tried following this guide ([link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)) and boot the CD drive in both UEFI and Legacy mode but I'm still not getting the _install alongside windows_. I also read on some other forums that EasyBCD with UEFI bios does not work sometimes. If it can help, in the boot priority list from my bios (UEFI) windows boots from a "_Windows Boot Manage_".

Comment: can you be a little bit more specific? For example do you have UEFI bios? What procedure are you using to install ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seams that after fiddling around a bit I managed to get the dual boot working!

How I did it:

1. Did a fresh install of Windows 7 N x64 on the entire drive.
2. Once the installation was finished I went into windows disk management by right clicking on the my computer icon on my desktop and selecting manage from the drop-down menu. On the right of the window that opens you'll find the disk management.
3. In disk management I shrieked the partition to the size I needed for my ubuntu installation (you can skip this if you are smarter than me and create a smaller partition for windows while installing it).
4. Rebooted my system and made sure that I booted off my CD/DVD/BD/USB drive (I use an external DVD drive) in UEFI mode (on my boot menu it says: UEFI:CD/DVD drive). You did it right if you get to this screen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6guvi.png) instead of this one (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM2WE.png)
5. Picked install ubuntu and got to the part where it asks you if you want to erase the entire disk, install along side windows (this time missing) or other more advanced stuff.
6. Select the other more advanced stuff and there you have to create your linux partitions on the space we freed up earlier. I personally created the following 3 partition:

   - 1x 500MB **/boot** partition in ext4.
   - 1x 30GB (more or less) **/** partition in ext4 (even if 20GB was more than enough).
   - 1x 4GB swap area partition.
   - If you want your home files to be on a separate partition you can create a /home ext4 partition.
7. Waited for the installation to finish and when the system rebooted I went into my boot menu again and chose to boot from Ubuntu (now I have a Ubuntu entry and a Windows Boot Manager entry in my boot manager menu, I chose to put ubuntu as the primary boot option and manage on which os to boot on first from GRUB) that loaded the good old GRUB with the options of booting to Ubunu 13.10 and Windows 7 N.

This was my experience with an ASrock A75M motherboard, I tried to be as general as possible so that it can be used as a guideline for anyone with UEFI dual boot problems. I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Try to recreate the bootloader of Windows 7 to login first. To do this, you will need a pendrive with a formatted ISO of Windows 7 x64 N (min 4GB) and Rufus Bootable USB program. You can download this for free from the internet. And also EasyBCD to create Windows boot loader with Grub emulated bootloader to boot your Ubuntu OS. This is steps:

1. Create a Windows 7 pendrive or prepare your Windows 7 installation DVD
2. When Windows 7 setup screen is displayed, select repair computer, and select from other menu windows `cmd`
3. Write this command - `bootrec /fixmbr and /rebuildbcd`
4. Now you should can login to your Windows system
5. Install EasyBCD program
6. Create new boot option with Grub emulator
7. Restart your computer, and select grub, when your Linux system

I hope that I could help you :)

Comment: I'll give it a try, I just reinstalled windows so I guess I will ha to install ubuntu again and skip to step 5. Correct?

Comment: I've suggested an edit to you answer. I was very unsure how point 3. was meant. Is the user really supposed to write "bootrec /fixmbr and /rebuildbcd" or are those two commands "bootrec /fixmbr; bootrec /rebuildbcd"? Point 7. Seems to be missing something at end. Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/383550/edit).